# Как поместить все jQuery скрипты в одном файле

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется несколько jQuery-скриптов, все они начинаются с

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    либо
function func(v) {
```

Можно ли их все поместить в один файл и не бояться, что что-то пойдет не так или перестанет работать или тут требуется все грамотно упорядочить?

Answer (score 1):

Если между ними нет зависимости, то можно попробовать, `ready` выполняется, когда загружен весь DOM ( но это не значит, что все скрипты успели подтянуться* ). Но чаще всего можете запихать все под одну ф-цию `ready`

"*" - могут не подтянуться только те скрипты, которые специально помечены как обрабатываемые асинхронно. Во всех остальных случаях `$().ready()` будет иметь готовый DOM с загруженными и обработанными скриптами.

Answer (score 0):

либо руками, либо сборщики есть.

*gulp*, к примеру.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?